# Octokit.net Pull request creation fails if adding .github folder

Tags: c#, git, octokit

Using octokit.net version 0.50.0 (latest as of now) to create a pull request from a feature branch branch1 into master.

Octokit lib throws validation error if feature branch has .github directory present.

Creation of pull request works if branch1 has .any_other_dir_name or .github111 but fails only when .github dir has been added by the feature branch.

Code:

```
var client = new GitHubClient(
new ProductHeaderValue("branch1"),
new InMemoryCredentialStore(new Credentials(accessToken, AuthenticationType.Oauth)),
gheURI);

await client.PullRequest.Create(remote.Id, new NewPullRequest(prTitle, "branch1", "master"));
```

Stack trace:

```
Octokit.ApiValidationException: Validation Failed
at Octokit.Connection.HandleErrors(IResponse response) in /home/runner/work/octokit.net/octokit.net/Octokit/Http/Connection.cs:line 703
at Octokit.Connection.RunRequest(IRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
.
.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"PullRequest","field":"head","code":"invalid"}],"documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.1/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the fix. Cause was "workflow" scope was missing.

workflow -  Grants the ability to add and update GitHub Actions workflow files. Workflow files can be committed without this scope if the same file (with both the same path and contents) exists on another branch in the same repository. Workflow files can expose GITHUB_TOKEN which may have a different set of scopes. For more information, see "Authentication in a workflow."

from
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps