# Create action.yml programmatically

Tags: c#, github-actions, octokit

I want to create new Github repositories programmatically with Octokit and each repo will have its own action.yml file to run the pipeline after all the codes are uploaded to repository. However the below command does not work stable. Sometimes it works and the yml file is created, and the pipeline is executed but sometimes the .github folder and action.yml are not created. If i change ".github/workflows/action.yml" to "ABC/workflows/action.yml" then the ABC folder and action.yml are always created but of course the pipeline cannot be created and executed. There is no exception is throwed, the code run successfully so i do not know what happen with octokit or github.

```
using Octokit;
...
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("..."));
var createFileRequest = new CreateFileRequest("update yml file", ymlfilecontent);
    var fileCreateResponse = client.Repository.Content.CreateFile(repId, ".github/workflows/action.yml", createFileRequest);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: File names cannot start with a period.

Comment: @jdweng, what do you mean with a period? there is no period here, right?

Comment: This line : ".github/workflows/action.yml"  I think it should be : "./github/workflows/action.yml"

Comment: no, action.yml file must be store under .github folder https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer from other post. In my case no exception is throwed, sometimes pipeline is created and sometimes not. But after updating the workflow scope, it seems work ok now.
[Octokit.net Pull request creation fails if adding .github folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599622/octokit-net-pull-request-creation-fails-if-adding-github-folder)